# what's my tomatoes problem? is that a fungs? what's the solution

Tags: diseases, tomatoes, fungus

[image: tomato fungus]

[image: tomato fungus]
it take all of the plants and we use several fungicide like chlorothalonil but it didn't work.

Comment: Tomatoes are such fragile plants when it comes to diseases and fungi.  You can spend hours combing the web to figure out which thing afflicts your plant.  I think Septoria Leaf Spot is much more common than believed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like early blight, which is a fungus. I usually control by being careful not to wet the plants when watering (only water the mulch around them), and growing them in a polytunnel which keeps them dry and relatively free of spores.

Infected plants can sometimes be saved by removing the affected parts, being careful not to spread spores to unaffected parts.